# Create a data frame with values column names matching another data frame's name

Tags: r, dataframe

I have some data frames, as follows

```
jack<-data.frame(c("M","F"),c(12,22))
colnames(jack)[1]<-"sex"
colnames(jack)[2]<-"age"

ethan<-data.frame(c("M","F"),c(34,99))
colnames(ethan)[1]<-"sex"
colnames(ethan)[2]<-"age"

ellie<-data.frame(c("M","F"),c(9,35))
colnames(ellie)[1]<-"sex"
colnames(ellie)[2]<-"age"
```

And a final data frame

```
mydf<-as.data.frame(c("martha","jack","luis","ethan","ellie"))
colnames(mydf)[1]<-"name"
```

I want to create a data frame with the value from the column `sex` of each data frame (`jack`, `ethan`, `ellie`), matching the `name` column of `mydf` (if there's a match - otherwise, put a 0). The final result should look like this

```
name sexM sexF
1 martha    0    0
2   jack   12   22
3   luis    0    0
4  ethan   34   99
5  ellie    9   35
```

I cannot understand how to combine these data frames. I used `merge` in the past, but this time I don't want to match row or column names, but the data frame (`jack`) with its matching row in `mydf` and insert its `age` value in the column.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `mget` on the `intersect`ing objects created in the global environment with the `names` from 'mydf' to return a `list` of key/values, then bind the list elements with `bind_rows`, reshape to 'wide' format with `pivot_wider` and later join with the original 'mydf'

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
mget(intersect(ls(), mydf$name)) %>% 
  bind_rows(.id = 'name') %>% 
  pivot_wider(names_from = 'sex', values_from = 'age', names_prefix = 'sex') %>% 
  right_join(mydf) %>%
  mutate(across(-name, replace_na, 0)) %>%
  arrange(match(name, mydf$name))
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 5 × 3
  name  sexM     sexF
  <chr>  <dbl> <dbl>
1 martha     0     0
2 jack      12    22
3 luis       0     0
4 ethan     34    99
5 ellie      9    35
```

---

Or may also use a `for` loop in `base R` by looping over the sequence of 'name', check if the `name` element `exists` as object in the global env, then assign the corresponding 'age' values for 'M', 'F' for already created 'sexM', 'sexF' (as 0 values)

```
mydf[c("sexM", "sexF")] <- 0

for(i in seq_along(mydf$name)) if(exists(mydf$name[i])) {
   tmp <- get(mydf$name[i])
   mydf$sexM[i] <- tmp$age[tmp$sex == "M"]
   mydf$sexF[i] <- tmp$age[tmp$sex == "F"]
}
```

-output

```
> mydf
    name sexM sexF
1 martha    0    0
2   jack   12   22
3   luis    0    0
4  ethan   34   99
5  ellie    9   35
```

Comment: I definitely need to learn better how to use the tidyverse... Thanks akrun!

Answer (score 2):

Here is an alternative approach combining base R and `tidyverse`:

```
library(tidyverse)
mydf_1 <- mydf %>% 
  mutate(sex = "0",
         age = 0) %>% 
select(sex, age, name)
  

my_list <- Map(cbind, my_list, name = names(my_list))
my_list %>% 
  bind_rows() %>% 
  bind_rows(mydf_1) %>% 
  pivot_wider(names_from= sex, values_from=age, values_fill = 0) %>% 
  select(-`0`)
```

```
  name       M     F
  <chr>  <dbl> <dbl>
1 jack      12    22
2 ethan     34    99
3 ellie      9    35
4 martha     0     0
5 luis       0     0
```

Comment: Hi tarJae, thanks for answering. I tried your solution as well (I also prefer it). I had to put my dataframes in a list and rename them as in `name`, and it worked.