# Use of pivot_wider() to match dataframes information

Tags: r, dplyr

I am trying to implement this procedure [Create a data frame with values column names matching another data frame's name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73006084/create-a-data-frame-with-values-column-names-matching-another-data-frames-name) but for a slightly different type of dataset. I have three dataframes that are a subset of ~100 dataframes:

```
jack<-data.frame(12,33,4)
colnames(jack)[1]<-"sex"
colnames(jack)[2]<-"age"
colnames(jack)[3]<-"mass"

ethan<-data.frame(0,4,54)
colnames(ethan)[1]<-"sex"
colnames(ethan)[2]<-"age"
colnames(ethan)[3]<-"mass"

ellie<-data.frame(5,0,88)
colnames(ellie)[1]<-"sex"
colnames(ellie)[2]<-"age"
colnames(ellie)[3]<-"mass"
```

Those data come originally in a .csv and I read them in R with `lapply`. For this example's sake, I stored them in a list:

```
mylist<-list(jack,ethan,ellie)
names(mylist)<-c("jack","ethan","ellie")
```

And a list of names (note that not all names have a corresponding dataframe)

```
mydf<-as.data.frame(c("martha","jack","luis","ethan","ellie"))
colnames(mydf)[1]<-"name"
```

Following the above mentioned procedure, I first create an empty dataframe with all the information:

```
mydf_1 <- mydf %>% 
  mutate(sex = 0,
         age = 0,
         mass = 0) %>% 
  select(sex,age,mass,name)
```

Then I create, for each dataframe, a column with its name

```
mylist <- Map(cbind, mylist, name = names(mylist))
```

Now I cannot understand what to put in `pivot_wider()` to have the values from `sex`, `age`, and `mass` matching the corresponding column and a 0 if there is no match (or if the value is 0). This is what I tried so far:

```
mydf_final <- mylist %>% 
  bind_rows() %>% 
  bind_rows(mydf_1) %>% 
  pivot_wider(names_from = c("sex","age","mass"), values_from = c(sex,age,mass), values_fill = 0) %>% 
  select(-`0`)
```

The desired output is a single dataframe.

Unluckily I am not very familiar with the tidyverse... I am using R 4.0.3

Comment: Is your desired final output a list or a dataframe?

Comment: The desired output is a data frame, sorry I forgot to add it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, it sounds like you want to merge everyone's (i.e. Jack's, Ethan's) dataframes together into one dataframe, but use zeroes to indicate if someone's (e.g., Martha's) data is missing. Rather than putting everything in a list, we can bind the three dataframes directly, merge with the five names, and replace any `NA` with zeroes.

EDIT: I've edited the below output so the code is less dependent on individual dataframes and tries to use the list more.

```
library(tidyverse)

# load in a list of .csv files
jack<-data.frame(12,33,4)
colnames(jack)[1]<-"sex"
colnames(jack)[2]<-"age"
colnames(jack)[3]<-"mass"
ethan<-data.frame(0,4,54)
colnames(ethan)[1]<-"sex"
colnames(ethan)[2]<-"age"
colnames(ethan)[3]<-"mass"
ellie<-data.frame(5,0,88)
colnames(ellie)[1]<-"sex"
colnames(ellie)[2]<-"age"
colnames(ellie)[3]<-"mass"
mylist<-list(jack,ethan,ellie)
names(mylist)<-c("jack","ethan","ellie")
rm(jack, ethan, ellie)

# load in a reference list that contains empty dataframes
mydf<-as.data.frame(c("martha","jack","luis","ethan","ellie"))
colnames(mydf)[1]<-"name"

# give everyone in `mylist` a variable that indicates its name
goodnames <- names(mylist)
mylist <- mapply(cbind, mylist, "name" = goodnames, SIMPLIFY = FALSE)
rm(goodnames)

# bind all the good dfs in mylist
final <- mylist %>%
  bind_rows() %>%
  merge(., mydf, by = "name", all.y = TRUE) %>%
  replace(is.na(.), 0)

head(final)
#>     name sex age mass
#> 1  ellie   5   0   88
#> 2  ethan   0   4   54
#> 3   jack  12  33    4
#> 4   luis   0   0    0
#> 5 martha   0   0    0
```

Comment: This is a nice approach, but in reality I have ~100 dataframes so it would be a bit messy... And each dataframes comes originally from a .csv that I read in R with lapply. I am modifying the question to specify this.

Comment: I see. Are the empty dataframes (Martha, Ethan) included in these 100 .csv files? Or do they come from a separate reference list?

Comment: Sorry, I mean the empty Martha and Luis dataframes

Comment: No, they come from a separate list (`mydf`).

Comment: Based on that, I've edited my post. I think the trick is to make sure each of the dfs from your many .csv files gets a variable that indicates its "name" so you can merge it with your reference list of names.

Comment: Thanks jrcalabrese, this works (on the original data I had to use `all = T` instead of `all.y = T`)

Answer (score 2):

Here is an alternative approach, if the output is like demonstrated by jrcalabrese:

```
library(dplyr)
bind_rows(list(jack=jack, ethan=ethan, ellie=ellie), .id = 'name') %>% 
  full_join(mydf, by="name") %>% 
  replace(is.na(.), 0)

    name sex age mass
1   jack  12  33    4
2  ethan   0   4   54
3  ellie   5   0   88
4 martha   0   0    0
5   luis   0   0    0
```

Comment: This is nice, although in this way it can be tricky to list all the df in `bind_rows()` if they are many.

Comment: If you have more dataframes it is no problem to load them in the environment and combine them with bind_rows. If this is needed please tell. I can show.

Answer (score 1):

This can be done in `base R` - loop over the `intersect`ing `names` from the 'mylist' and the `names` column and then do the assign

```
mydf[c("sex", "age", "mass")] <- 0
for(nm in intersect(mydf$name, names(mylist))) 
   mydf[mydf$name == nm, c("sex", "age", "mass")] <- mylist[[nm]]
```

-output

```
> mydf
    name sex age mass
1 martha   0   0    0
2   jack  12  33    4
3   luis   0   0    0
4  ethan   0   4   54
5  ellie   5   0   88
```

Comment: I like the base R approach but I think something is missing (some {} maybe?) as it is not working for me. I tried this without success:
`mylist[[nm]] <- for(nm in intersect(mydf$name, names(mylist))){
  mydf[mydf$name == nm, c("sex", "age", "mass")] 
  mylist }`

Comment: @LisaTedeschi your statement at the end `mylist` is not needed as we are updating `mydf` on each iteration.   When there is a single statement, there is no need for `{}`.  I tried again and it is working fine for me